# Recyclerview throws nullexception error for textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

EDIT:
I am trying to populate firebase recyclerview from firebase and it looks like everything is fine with reaching out for the data but when it comes to populate the textview it throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)
at com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.DummyFragment$1.onBindViewHolder(DummyFragment.java:64)
                      at com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.DummyFragment$1.onBindViewHolder(DummyFragment.java:55)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:118)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here is my fragment class

```
public class DummyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;
private RecyclerView mProduceList = null;

public Context c;
private LinearLayoutManager manager;

public DummyFragment() {
}

public static DummyFragment newInstance() {
    DummyFragment fragment = new DummyFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(c);
    mProduceList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mProduceList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    DatabaseReference productRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    Query productQuery = productRef.orderByKey();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions productOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>().setQuery(productQuery, Product.class).build();

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(productOptions) {
        @Override
        public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            return new ProductViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, int position, Product product) {
            viewHolder.post_name.setText(product.getTitle());
            viewHolder.post_type.setText(product.getDesc());
        }
    };

    mProduceList.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
}

public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    TextView post_name;
    TextView post_type;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        post_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
        post_type = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.productDesc);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        post_name.setText(title);
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        post_type.setText(desc);
    }
}
}
```

and here is my model class

```
public class Product {
@Exclude
private String Title;
@Exclude private String Desc;
int image;

public Product()
{

}
@Keep
public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}
@Keep
public void setTitle(String title){
    Title = title;
}
public String getDesc(){
    return Desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc){
    Desc = desc;
}
public int getImage(){
    return image;
}
public void setImage(int image){
    this.image=image;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Product model = (Product) o;

    return (Title == null ? model.Title == null : Title.equals(model.Title))
            && (Desc == null ? model.Desc == null : Desc.equals(model.Desc));
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = Title == null ? 0 : Title.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (Desc == null ? 0 : Desc.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Model{" +
            "mTitle='" + Title + '\'' +
            ", mImage='" + Desc + '\'' +
            '}';
}

}
```

I am not sure if my model class is set up properly and also if my viewholder is right. I am relatively new with Firebase and I am really struggling with this recyclerview so if anyone can provide a solution it will be massively appreciated.
Here are the layouts

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="70sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Card Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f7f7f8"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="-120dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/productsdarken"/>
<!--  Recycler View  -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check textview id in R.layout.dummy_fragment. You have inflated the same layout for fragment as well as recyclerview item.

Comment: Please add layout code also

Comment: Are you sure id **productTitle** exist in this layout **dummy_fragment** ?

Comment: They are displayed in a cardview and the dummy_fragment holds the recyclerview only

Comment: @redberry where you specified item layout for recyclerview?

Comment: @redberry you have inflated the same layout for fragment as well as recyclerview item, look at onCreateView & onCreateViewHolder. R.layout.dummy_fragment is inflated in both of them

Comment: @Gautam so I should inflate item_row than is that right?

Comment: @redberry thats why it is null, you have to inflate the item layout in your adapter instead of RecyclerView layout. inflate layout that has **productTitle** in your adapter and thats it.

Comment: @redberry yes ( whatever name you have given for the other layout which contains your cardview) . It should be infalted in onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: @Gautam its not giving me the error anymore but this is what I am getting now 
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for protuctDesc found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for productName found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for producDesc found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for productName found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product

Comment: @redberry i thinks it due to mismatches between your field and your setter. From the error i think its finding protuctDesc instead of Desc which is decalred in your product class. Try changing the Desc to protuctDesc and also its getter/setter methods i.e getDesc to getProductDesc and same for other field decalred as productName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
viewHolder.post_name.setText(product.getTitle());
viewHolder.post_type.setText(product.getDesc());
```

to this:

```
viewHolder.setTitle(product.getTitle());
viewHolder.setDesc(product.getDesc());
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code...? How is it possible.

Comment: @PeterHaddad can you explain it to me how it will know for which view text needs to be set ?

Comment: @PeterHaddad  Can you please explain. I am also not getting this that how will it know which textview to set

Comment: @VishvaDave there is no setText(), the holder class has two method settitle and setDesc, to be able to access those methods in the onbindviewholder, you need to use object.setTitle() and object.setDesc()

Comment: the answer is 100% correct and its silly that it got downvoted, probably someone who does not understand

Comment: I am just trying that now, thanks! Hopefully it will work

Comment: @PeterHaddad oh i missed those methods. It will definitely work but i don't think thats the cause for NPE. If your view is null then even those method call will result in NPE yet again.

Comment: @PeterHaddad this + changing the layout worked out fine, Thanks for that!

Comment: @Gautam those two that he is accesing are variables declared in the inner class `TextView post_name;
    TextView post_type;` that is why he got the error null point exception

Comment: @PeterHaddad It is working fine but it saying
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for protuctDesc found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for productName found on class com.example.cyrenians.cyreniansprototypenew.Product

Comment: @redberry in your database, the fields need to be called `Desc` and `Title`, the same as in your POJO class

Comment: @PeterHaddad working awesome just now, thanks very much saved me so much time

Comment: @redberry no problem glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I use a dimen value in `dimens.xml` without `dp`. Example

```
<dimen name="dp_50">50</dimen>
```

It look strange because application still build successful and the error message look not relevant.

To fix problem, just change to

```
<dimen name="dp_50">50dp</dimen>
```

Hope it help anyone